# Run functions over many dataframes, add results to another dataframe, and dynamically name the resulting column with the name of the original df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many different tables that all have different column names and each refer to an outcome, like glucose, insulin, leptin etc (except keep in mind that the tables are all gigantic and messy with tons of other columns in them as well).

I am trying to generate a report that starts empty but then adds columns based on functions applied to each of the glucose, insulin, and leptin tables.

I have included a very simple example - ignore that the function makes little sense. The below code works, but I would like to, instead of copy + pasting final_report["outcome"] = over and over again, just run the find_result function over each of glucose, insulin, and leptin and add the "glucose_result", "insulin_result" and "leptin_result" to the final_report in one or a few lines.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd

ids = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4]
timepoint = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,1,2,3,4,5,6]
outcome = [2,3,4,5,6,7,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,4,5,8,4,5,6,2,3]

glucose = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,
                   'timepoint':timepoint,
                   'outcome':outcome})

insulin = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,
                   'timepoint':timepoint,
                   'outcome':outcome})

leptin = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,
                   'timepoint':timepoint,
                   'outcome':outcome})

ids = [1,2,3,4]
start = [1,1,1,1]
end = [6,6,6,6]


final_report = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids,
                             'start':start,
                             'end':end})

def find_result(subject, start, end,  df):
    df = df.loc[(df["id"] == subject) & (df["timepoint"] >= start) & (df["timepoint"] <= end)].sort_values(by = "timepoint")
    return df["timepoint"].nunique()

final_report['glucose_result'] = final_report.apply(lambda x: find_result(x['id'], x['start'], x['end'], glucose), axis=1)

final_report['insulin_result'] = final_report.apply(lambda x: find_result(x['id'], x['start'], x['end'], insulin), axis=1)

final_report['leptin_result'] = final_report.apply(lambda x: find_result(x['id'], x['start'], x['end'], leptin), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use this code structure, you can create a simple dictionary with your dataframes and their names and loop through them, creating new columns with programmatically assigned names:

```py
input_dfs = {"glucose": glucose, "insulin": insulin, "leptin": leptin}
for name, df in input_dfs.items():
    final_report[f"{name}_result"] = final_report.apply(
        lambda x: find_result(x['id'], x['start'], x['end'], df),
        axis=1
    )
```

Output:

```
   id  start  end  glucose_result  insulin_result  leptin_result
0   1      1    6               6               6              6
1   2      1    6               6               6              6
2   3      1    6               3               3              3
3   4      1    6               6               6              6
```